# Can You Increment A Variable Inside A Function Call In Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, swift5

I am revising some code from someone else and they are making this function call:

```
 features.insert(σ.min(values: yArray)!, at: featCount += 1)
```

This receives a "Cannot convert value of type '()' to expected argument type 'Int'" error message, is there any way I can increment this variable in a different way inside this function call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `featCount += 1` – unlike unsupported `featCount++` – doesn't return anything (that's what the error states) so you need an extra line.

- If the variable is supposed to be incremented **before** being used in the function

  ```
  featCount += 1
  features.insert(σ.min(values: yArray)!, at: featCount)
  ```
- If the variable is supposed to be incremented **after** being used in the function

  ```
  features.insert(σ.min(values: yArray)!, at: featCount)
  featCount += 1
  ```